# Can we add event listeners to "Vega-Lite" specification?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, vega, vega-lite

I am new to Vega and Vega-Lite. I am creating a simple bar chart using Vega-Lite but I am not able to add any event listeners e.g. "hover".

I want to hover a bar and change the color of the bar.

Comment: You have not provided any code. SO is not a code-writing service. Look at the end of http://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/embed.html. `chart({el:"#vis"})` is a `view` as is `result.view` from `vg.embed("#vis", embedSpec, function(error, result) {};` You can use any `.on('event', fnctn)` listener in there. When called, the handler has 2 parameters, the second is the `item`. You'll need to inspect it to see if you can indeed use it. Full Vega has spec-able event listeners.

Comment: You have not provided any code here. I believe you can use Vega-Lite API to implement a hover effect. Please refer to [Vega-Lite API reference](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_hover)

Answer (score 9):

If you're using [Vega-Embed](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed), it returns a promise with a reference to the view which allows you to use `addEventListener` - [explained in the docs here](https://github.com/vega/vega-view#event-handling).

Here is an example:

```
const width = 600
const color = blue
embed(element, {
    $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/3.0.0-rc6.json',
    data: { 'values': data },
    mark: {
        type: 'line',
        color,
        point: {
            color,
        }
    },
    width,
    height: width / 2,
    encoding: {
        'x': {
            field: 'label',
            type: 'temporal',
        },
        'y': {
            field: 'value',
            type: 'quantitative',
        },
    }
}).then(({spec, view}) => {
    view.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event, item) {
        console.log(item.datum)
    })
})
```

Comment: Is it also possible to update a field and re-render the view? I tried item.datum.label = "new label" followed by view.run() without success.