# Add event listener to VegaWidget in Jupyter for getting selected data "out" of vega

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets, vega

I would like to combine two VegaWidgets graphics in a Jupyter notebook for overview and detail, where one can make a brush selection in the overview graphic, the selected data items are processed in Python and then displayed in the detail graphic.

Is it possible to add a listener to a Vega signal or a mouse listener to an ipyvega widget?

What I found so far, are event listeners for

- [getting data from a ipywidgets button into Vega](https://github.com/vega/ipyvega/blob/master/notebooks/Widget.ipynb) (the reverse way)
- [vega-embed in a normal webpage with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300914/can-we-add-event-listeners-to-vega-lite-specification/52865102)
- [Observable](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/observing-vega-signals)
- [R Shiny](https://rdrr.io/cran/vegawidget/man/shiny-getters.html)